# How to display the data in browser?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I want to send some data(hello world) using python socket io client to flask socket io...but nothing is displayed in browser

**this is my client code**

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

def on_aaa_response(args):
  print('on_aaa_response', args['data'])

socketIO = SocketIO('127.0.0.1', 5000)
socketIO.on('aaa_response', on_aaa_response)
socketIO.emit('aaa')
socketIO.wait(seconds=1)
```

**this is my flask code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('aaa')
def test_connect():
print("Welcome, aaa received")
emit('aaa_response', {'data': 'Server'})
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'Hello, World!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code. Instead, paste it directly into the question.

Comment: i have edited the above question..kindly help me with this

Comment: Tested your code, it works as intended and I can't see a problem here. P.S. There is no browser in your example and it's mention in question causes confusion.

Comment: @Fian I want to display the data in web page using flask

Comment: Sooo, we advise you to learn a little about web-development, stackoverflow is not a free consult-me-and-do-my-job-for-me service.

Comment: i found out how to display the processed data in webpage using flask....but the problem is am not able to create the communication between python scoketio and flask socketio